# Nokia Here hijacks window's DOMMouseScroll events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, here-api

Nokia Here hijacks window's `DOMMouseScroll` events.

I register the event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', 
                        function(){console.log('mouse wheel')}, 
                        true);
```

But it is never triggered when using the mouse wheel over the Here Map.

My guess is that Here Map's API catches the event before my handler does and then cancels the event.

How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what functionality you need from the map, you can either disable map interaction entirely or just disable mouse scroll.

### Option 1 - Disable map interaction

When you create the map, you can add components to specify which functionality you want:

```
map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
  center: [40.664167, -73.838611],
  zoomLevel: 15,
  components: [
    new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
  ]
});
```

The `nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior` component loads the default set of interactions (`zoom.MouseWheel`, `zoom.DoubleClick`, etc). See http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior.html for more.

If you don't include that component, the map won't capture any of those things.

### Option 2 - Disable only MouseScroll

If you do want *some* of the behaviours but not the mousescroll, you can load the `Behavior` component then remove the specific one you don't want:

```
map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
  center: [40.664167, -73.838611],
  zoomLevel: 15,
  components: [
    new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
  ]
});

map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.MouseWheel"));
```

This would leave the double-click zooming, dragging and the rest of the map functionality but not catch the scroll event.

### Option 3 - Custom zoomMouseWheel

If you need the map's zoom scroll functionality and still want the mousescroll events, you can first disable the built-in behaviour (option 2 above) then implement your own scroll listener:

```
function zoomMouseWheel(e) {
  var newZoomLevel;
  var toX = e.x;
  var toY = e.y;
  if (e.wheelDelta) {
      newZoomLevel = map.zoomLevel+e.wheelDelta;
  } else if (e.detail) {
      newZoomLevel = map.zoomLevel+(e.detail * -1);
  }
  map.setZoomLevel(newZoomLevel, "default", toX, toY)
};

mapContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', zoomMouseWheel, true);
mapContainer.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', zoomMouseWheel, true);

document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(){console.log('mouse wheel')}, true);
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(){console.log('mouse wheel')}, true);
```

*NOTE: Tested in Chrome & Firefox on OS X, it may be necessary to modify the wheelDelta calculation for other browsers*

Comment: thanks for the answer but disabling the MouseWheel is not an option. I want the MouseWheel to work for the map but also to be able to listen to that event with javascript.

Comment: Hmmm... in versions < 2.3, the scroll event was exposed in the map Display object so it was possible to attach a listener. I've updated with a third option that seems to do the trick but might require a bit of work to guarantee browser compatibility.

Comment: that actually works! Option 2 + Option 3 from your answer. Thanks a lot! Nokia Here API v. 2.5.3